# How to add a [z] list to an [x, y] coordinate list?

Tags: python, list, zip

I have a situation in 3 dimensional modeling where the x and y coordinates come from one source and the z coordinates and the z coordinates come from another. `zip()` is almost but not quite the right tool for the job.  Can someone tell me a nice, elegant, pythonic way to do this?

Input:

```
xy = [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
z =[1,2,2,1]
```

Desired output:

```
xyz=[[0,1,1],[1,0,2],[0,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use list comprehension

```py
xyz = [xy[i] + [z[i]] for i in range(len(xy))]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` is right tool, just use a list comprehension:

```
xyz = [x+[y] for x,y in zip(xy,z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with using `zip()`?

If you thought about the *unpythonic* way of solving this, with a for loop iterating over indexes, you're always using the elements of `xy`, and `z` in pairs.

```py
xyz = []
for i in range(len(xy)):
   xyz.append(xy + [z])
```

You can make the index based for loop more *pythonic* by using `zip()` instead.

```py
xyz = []
for xy, z in zip(xy, z);
    xyz.append(xy + [z])
```

You can then make the code even more *pythonic* by using a list comprehension instead of a for loop.

```py
xyz = [xy + [z] for xy, z in zip(xy, z)]
```